# Create a Report Showing Email Addresses of Customer Who Ordered a Specific Product

Tags: magento-1.9, module, reports

I'm trying to do something that seems simple but we've been pulling hair out here trying to get it done.

We have a specific product on our store that has been downloaded more than 2,000 times. When we run a report on downloads, we can see the product and the number of downloads.

We sure would like to be able to email all of the people who downloaded that product. There has to be a way to generate a report that tells us everyone who downloaded this product, include the person's email address, and export it to Excel.

Please tell me I'm missing something obvious!!

Answer (score 0):

To create a custom report you can use this Free Custom Report Writer Extension: http://extensionsstore.biz/extension-packages/custom-report-writer.html

If you need to export the results you can go with the paid version: http://extensionsstore.biz/extension-packages/custom-report-writer-with-export-for-magento.html.